# How can I use cron to edit a line in a file?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, cron, text-processing

I'm using Ubuntu terminal and I want to tell this to my crontab;

Go to `test.cfg` file, open it, replace line 35 with `x`.

Is this possible? I have looked around but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Cron is for repeating tasks. How often do you want to replace line 35 with an x? Every minute or every second sunday in march, for example?

Comment: This is a strange request but if line 35 of your test.cfg file is unique, the command `sed -i 's/<copy-line-35-here>/x/' /path/to/test.cfg`, when executed by cron as a repeating job, will do it. Make sure to confirm line 35 is unique because the `sed` command will replace ALL matching strings, it doesn't care about line numbers. If you explain your use-case further you may get a better answer (posting as comment because I'm not sure exactly what you want to do here...)

Answer (score 4):

To replace the 35th line in the file `/path/to/test.cfg`
with the text `x` the following command will do:

```
sed -i '35 c x' /path/to/test.cfg
```

To have that run every fifth minute on Sundays in March 
create the following cronjob via `crontab -e`:

```
*/5 * * 3 0 /bin/sed -i '35 c x' /path/to/test.cfg
```

Comment: @J.Doe You are welcome. Although I don't see the purpose of this. While I think the answer is technically correct, it appears not very sensible to me to keep replacing a certain line in a file via cron. Why do you need that? Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/387352).

Comment: I'm getting super confused. I have looked around and is sed command to edit crontab file? Let's forget crontab. Let's say all I want to do is I want to open test.cfg file and replace line 16 with x but with using only commands. How would I do it? I tried yours and Tom's method manually but there are no changes happening in the file.

Comment: +1 Nice answer, I had no idea sed could target specific lines. Time for me to read that man page again...

Comment: @J.Doe Oops. I forgot the `-i` in the first command (now updated). It tells `sed` to edit the file _in-place_, i.e. instead of printing the result of the manipulation it changes the actual file.